# Python custom library, nested import problem

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am creating my own python library: `toolbox`. In the end I want to be able to do: `from toolbox.printing import warn`.

My architecture looks like this:

```
repo
|--toolbox
|----__init__.py
|----printing
|------__init__.py
|------utils.py
|--demo.py
|--setup.py
```

Here is `toolbox/printing/utils.py`:

```py
def warn(text: str):
    print(str)
```

I was able to run `demo.py` with this:

```py
from toolbox.printing import warn
warn("This is a warning")
```

with `toolbox/__init__.py`:

```py
from .printing import warn
```

and `toolbox/printing/__init__.py`

```py
from .utils import warn
```

This works fine when executing `python demo.py`.
However if in another project I do `pip install git+myRepo.git`, the import does not work. The error depended on what I put in the `__init__.py` files: ModuleNotFOundError, CircularImports, ...
Here is my `setup.py` file:

```py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name='toolbox',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='MyName',
    author_email='myEmail',
    description='Usefull functions for my personnal use',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url='myRepo',
    project_urls = {
        "Bug Tracker": "myRepo"
    },
    license='MIT',
    packages=['toolbox'],
    install_requires=['requests',
                      'boto3',
                      'configparser'],
)
```

Could someone explain me:

- What I should put in the `__init__.py` files so that it works?
- What exactly is happening here? Is this a difference between modules and libraries?

Thanks!

See above for mor details.

Comment: in `setup.py`'s `setuptools.setup()` the value for `packages` should be a list of all packages and sub-packages. So it should be `['toolbox', 'toolbox.printing']`. You might want to use `setuptools.find_packages()` instead of creating this list yourself.